# why analytic signal can separate into odd and even part

Tags: signal-processing, fourier-transform

According to the following video at 3:50，the man said that by the reason of Fourier series,the f(t) can divided into odd and even part. I understand the function of fourier series,but I still can't figure out.More specific,please!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKLrBehT33s

Comment: Any function (with a domain symmetric about $0$) can be split into even and odd parts:  let $f_e(x)=\frac 12 \times (f(x)+f(-x))$ and $f_o(x)=\frac 12 \times (f(x)-f(-x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sum $e(t):=f(t)+f(-t)$. This is obviously an even function ($e(t)=e(-t)$). And consider $o(t):=f(t)-f(-t)$, which is obviously an odd function ($o(t)=-o(-t)$).

Then, $e(t)+o(t)=2f(t)$, so that these two functions define a decomposition of $f$ as the sum of an even and an odd function.

Example:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your proof.  Now, I suddenly figure if out. Can I explain it by Fourier sine series is odd function and cosine series is even.then any function can be these two combination?

Comment: @RichardTsai: indeed, but that's nothing new. A Fourier series is usually made of sine and cosine terms.